# Perl Split with array results in uninitialized value

Tags: perl, split, scalar

I have the same Perl script running on two different machines (Redhat & SUSE). On SUSE the script runs fine but it does not on Redhat.
This is the whole script I'm running as is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$str = "Cat|Dog|Bird"; 
$number = split /\|/, $str;
$type = @_[0];
print "number of args: $number and type is: $type \n";
```

I get 2 different outputs

SUSE:

```
number of args: 3 and type is: Cat
```

Redhat:

```
number of args: 3 and type is:
```

I want to know what could be causing this??? In the first one `$type` is initialized somehow

Note: I'm ignoring the warning *"Scalar value @_[0] better written as $_[0]"* as it makes no difference if I change it. The output will be the same.

Comment: Which Perl versions are you running on the two different systems? Check `perl -v`.

Comment: perl versions 5.16.3(redhat) and 5.10.0(suse)

Comment: *"I'm ignoring the warning "Scalar value @_[0] better written as $_[0]" as it makes no difference"* It is *never* a good idea to ignore warnings: they are generated for a reason. Changing `@_[0]` to `$_[0]` *does* make a difference: it changes the expression from a single-element array slice to a single array element, which is what you intended. Whether or not a piece of code "works" is a very poor measure of its correctness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) has this

> Prior to Perl 5.11, it also overwrote @_ with the list in void and scalar context. If you target old perls, beware.

The first subsequent *stable release* is v5.12, whereafter `split` no longer overwrites `@_` if it is called in scalar context: the list of fields is simply discarded, but the *number* of fields is still returned. (Note that calling `split` in void context is therefore completely ineffective: neither the list nor its size are saved anywhere.) It would previously overwrite the parameters to the current subroutine, and so was a very bad idea

Your code should look like this

```
my $str    = 'Cat|Dog|Bird';
my @fields = split /\|/, $str;
my $number = @fields;
my $type   = $fields[0];

print "number of args: $number and type is: $type \n";
```

This will work correctly on all versions of Perl